# The Terminal on my raspbery pi is gone

Tags: pi-4

I turned on my raspberry pi 4 today and was going to open the command terminal and noticed that it just isn't there. Not on the bar or as a desktop shortcut. It wasn't anywhere in the menu either. Does anyone know how to fix this or has this happened to anyone else.

Comment: Just found out I can still open the terminal using ctrl+alt+f1 but still can't access it from desktop menu or the bar.

Comment: What OS? What did you do?

Comment: Just the normal Pi OS, yesterday I installed snaps and the snap store onto it but I could still access the terminal from the menu, taskbar, and desktop like normal.